# Drupal Commerce - Sort products in view priced lowest to highest

Tags: 7, views, commerce

This seems like it should be super simple. I'm trying to sort my products by price (from lowest to highest) in my view, and no matter what I do, nothing seems to work. See below the setup of my current view. At the moment, the below settings give me the lower priced products first (e.g. it shows products ranged $4-9 before products ranged $50-90), but they're all mixed up (e.g. $4, $7, $4, $9...) when it should be $4, $4, $7, $9...

I hope that makes sense.

[image]

Comment: Maybe you have to add another Sort criteria that sorts them within the range. Can you explain more about your aggregation settings?

Answer (score 0):

It isn't clear to me why you're sorting based on some sort of standard deviation here (or why you're using aggregation at all). If you really just want to sort a list of products by price in a taxonomy term, you should just keep aggregation off and sort on the price directly.

If you need aggregation on, you're going to need to explain the intent behind this sort method.